# Is the term "invert level" applicable as the "floor" of a pressure pipe or the bottom of the trench?

Tags: pipelines

I have always used the term "invert level" as the "floor level" of pressure and gravity pipelines alike. A long section for pressure pipe from another engineer came across my desk where his "invert level" indicates the bottom of the trench  as the level below the pipeline (includes bedding)

I have gone through various handbooks at the office and did an online search, I can not find a distinction between pressure vs gravity pipes, but the reference often refer to gravity pipelines or channels.

Is the term "invert level" applicable as the "floor" of a pressure pipe or the bottom of the trench?

Comment: Why not ask all your colleagues for their opinion?

Comment: I did ask most colleagues for their opinion and whether they have documentation which may assist. On the side, Engineers as a society are not a democracy ... we follow the scientific process and try to avoid "designing by opinion or democracy"

Comment: So what do they "know" compared to what you have "always used" ? That is, what do they say the scientific process says it is?

Comment: No, it's not what I meant to say at all. Invoking "scientific process" or method was a bad choice of words. What I meant to say is that we rather want to have the correct information from literature than depending on a variety of experiences. We do have consensus on the matter, but we still could be wrong, hence the query

Comment: my view you should clearly define what you mean be the term and go ahead and use it.

Comment: So there is no recognised standard?